# how to Integrate h2o template engine with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having problem to integrate h2o php template engine in codeigniter.

any suggestion will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Probably because the water is extinguishing the fire on your code?

Comment: ((slow clap)) @BoltClock

Comment: @pygorex1: Ha, I just have to hand that comment vote to you :)

Comment: @BoltClock: You seem to have good grasp of the problem. I high-five you with an upvote.

Comment: @BoltClock:-  good sense of humor  :)

Comment: +1 simply for the irony of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried so far? Loading it as a library? etc; Give us some detail.

You are basically trying to merge one application with another (not in a very pretty way either) in the hopes of just having visual output from h2o instead of CI.

My thought would be forgo the `VIEW` method in CI if you want to use the template system with h2o.  Then you would include in your controller like a library and output using the method as utilized in h2o:

```
$h2o = new h2o('templates/index.html');
echo $h2o->render(array('name'=>'Peter Jackson'));
```

you would put your templates folder into your root like so:

```
/templates
```

This is just a process that I would follow if I wanted to integrate something into CI that would replace the VIEW.

Comment: i didn't got exact solution but. i got an idea. anyway thanks for the suggestion.